# How do I hide the status bar in an iOS app without causing the UINavigationBar to jump?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, modalviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

I have a view controller that needs to hide the status bar before presenting a modal and after that modal is dismissed.

This is not as simple as overriding `prefersStatusBarHidden` and then setting `modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance` because that will also cause a jump given I am presenting over the current context (the modal is a pull down to dismiss).

Consider the instagram story UX, as an example. When tapping on a story, you actually see the status bar disappear before the story modal is presented. Then when pulling the story down to dismiss it, the modal view controller actually must be completely dismissed before they redisplay the status bar.

I originally implemented a custom status bar that would do a lot of tricks to maintain the proper size and position given the device / iOS combos (iOS 10 & 11 + iPhone X and non iPhone X) but that was proving to be very painful unless I detected the device and hardcoded the safe area / layout guide dimensions. So currently I am attempting to do this with the stock UINavigationBar.

Any idea how this is possible?

Comment: Why do you repeatedly refer to the storyboard as 'story'?

Comment: @ElTomato Because I am referring to instagram stories - the feature in the app that pulls up a modal UX. It has nothing to do with storyboards.

Comment: Oops...  I'm sorry about that, then.

Comment: Does this answer potentially help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239687/setnavigationbarhidden-animation-not-working-as-expected-on-iphone-x

Comment: @KaneCheshire - no, i don't want to hide the navigation bar, i want to keep it exactly where it is and hide the status bar

Comment: ok I believe what they are doing is creating a new `UIWindow` and displaying that over the current `keyWindow` ...this seems to be the only way this is possible

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @VinGazoil I think creating a new `UIWindow` is the right solution. I came up with something temporary but I don't think it's the best way to do it. I will investigate the `UIWindow` solution if my priorities allow it.